# prime number related proof

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I want to prove if following is true for every integer a,b and c

$$a^2 - b^2 = cp $$

then p|(a+b)  or  p|(a-b) where p is a prime number. Any suggestion, help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Since $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$, you have $cp = (a+b)(a-b)$, hence $p | (a+b)(a-b)$, hence $p|(a+b)$ or $p|(a-b)$.

Comment: how can you conlude just like that?

Comment: One can either define prime numbers by that property, or appeal to unique prime factorization. If $p \mid xy$, then $p$ is in the factorization of $xy$, so it's either a factor of $x$ or of $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a^2-b^2=cp\implies a^2\equiv b^2\pmod p$$

If $p|a, b^2\equiv0\pmod p\implies b\equiv0$

Else $(ab,p)=1\implies \left(\frac ab\right)^2\equiv1\pmod p$

Now use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366800/solution-set-for-congruence-x2-equiv-1-mod-m)

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit please? It looks incorrect

Comment: @BlediBoss, from the link, we have $\frac ab\equiv\pm1\pmod p\implies a\equiv\pm b\pmod p$

Comment: @BlediBoss, or as mjqxxxx has pointed out $\frac{(a+b)(a-b)}p=c$ which is an integer $\implies p$ must divide at least one of $a+b,a-b$

Comment: I mean before we come to that step. My aim was to show    p|(a+b) or p|(a-b) . And one more thing, I guess it should be gcd(ab,p) = 1 at your answer.

Comment: @BlediBoss, the question does not say $(ab,p)=1$ or not? From the link, we know $x^2\equiv1\pmod p\iff x\equiv\pm1$

Comment: yeah that's true. Once more you mean (ab,p)=1 or gcd(ab,p) = 1 ? And what has that to do with the answer  p|(a+b) or p|(a-b)?  I'm so confused

Comment: @BlediBoss, $(A,B)$ conventionally means gcd$(A,B)$