# Find all the natural solutions to this diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all the natural solutions to this diophantine equation
$968m =n^2-54257$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $54257\equiv49\pmod {968}$ and $\displaystyle 968m=n^2-54257\implies n^2\equiv54257 \pmod {968}$

$\displaystyle\implies n^2\equiv49=7^2\pmod {968}$

As $\displaystyle968=2^3\cdot11^2$

we need $\displaystyle(i)n^2\equiv49\pmod{2^3}\equiv1$ 
(See [Prove that $x^{2} \equiv 1 \pmod{2^k}$ has exactly four incongruent solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25128/prove-that-x2-equiv-1-pmod2k-has-exactly-four-solution-incongruent-sol))

and $\displaystyle(i)n^2\equiv49\pmod{11^2}$
Use [Solutions of the congruence $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345668/solutions-of-the-congruence-x2-equiv-1-pmodm)  or 
[solution set for congruence $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366800/solution-set-for-congruence-x2-equiv-1-mod-m)